# Add files to Home Videos without physically copying the file

Tags: itunes, video

I have a wifi based disk on which I have many movies. I can access this disk from my mac finder and see all the files.

I want to add these files to my itunes home videos folder without physically copying the files from the wifi disk.

I thought the right way to do this was to open itunes movies -> home videos then drag and drop the files from the finder on the home videos.

but in my case, it starts physically copying 100s of those files from the wifi disk to the local storage of the computer.

I don't want this.

I want itunes to just use the wifi disk. I know this is possible and I have done it from other computers.... but right now I am not able to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iTunes menu > Preferences > Advanced tab > uncheck "Copy files to iTunes Media folder ..."

Note this will disable it for music and other media, too. If you want to keep using it for music and other media, disable the option, add all your videos, then re-enable it. iTunes will then keep track of the fact that the videos are in one place, and your music will still be copied into the iTunes Media folder when added in the future.

If you do this, *do not* select File > Library > Consolidate Files, or it will attempt to copy all your videos into the iTunes Media folder.

Answer (score 0):

In recent macOS versions (12.3.1 at time of writing) we use the "TV" app. And while holding down the option key, we drag the movie file into Library > Home Videos section of the TV app. It should keep the file from copying anywhere such that playback is done from the source location.